# A method that returns a value obtained in an asynchronous call

Tags: java, jersey

I know it's a beginner's doubt, but I'll try to be as objective as possible.

I would like to know the correct way to make my method return a value that is obtained through an asynchronous call within my own method.
Below is a simplified code of the way I'm trying.

For clarification questions, I'm trying to do this in one of the endpoits of my webservice (jersey)

```
@POST
@Path("authentication")
public String auth(String token) {

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();

  new AuthUserToken(token, AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Token decodedToken) {
            String uID = decodedToken.getUid();
            String email = decodedToken.getEmail();

            User user = new UserDAO().find(uid, email);
            if ( usuario != null ){
                response.setCode(Response.Status.ACCEPTED.name());
                response.setMessage("User found");
                response.setPayload(gson.toJson(user));

            } else{
                response.setCode(Response.Status.ACCEPTED.name());
                response.setMessage("User not found");
                response.setPayload("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("onFailure = "+ e.getMessage());
            response.setCode(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.name());
            response.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            response.setPayload("");
        }
    });

    return new Gson().toJson(response);
}
```

Comment: There's an interface called `Future` that you want [to learn about](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: does this code not work as-is? any error messages?

Comment: Yes. When I am calling UserDao() on OnSuccess I get this error:
  "Error Exception in thread" pool-2-thread-2 "java.lang.NullPointerException" . My approach is correct?